# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls'

Tags: python-3.6, django-1.9

Whenever I try to run "python manage.py runserver" in Powershell as admin, I get an **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls'**. Can somebody help me please?!

I'm using django 1.9 and python 3.6

IN POWERSHELL

File     "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\website_new\website_new\urls.py", line 3,
from django.urls import path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls'

IN URLS.PY:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
django.urls.path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, you are already using python 3.6 so you need to upgrade django to latest version which is greater than 2. For those who are using python 2.7, python2.7 don't support django 2 so you can't install django.urls.

On PowerShell

```
pip install -U django
```

Verification

```
PS C:\Users\xyz> python
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 25 2018, 15:27:00) [MSC v.1910 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.urls import path
>>>
```

As next prompt came, it means it is installed now and ready to use.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work!

```
from django.urls import path
```

It was introduced in django 2.0, you need to upgrade your django version for it to work. Kindly check the documentation for django 2.0 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.urls import path
```

is new feature of Django 2.0 , so upgrade your Django please...